# Intent extras being lost when sending with PendingIntent for GCM

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a `notification` but when sending it using `PendingIntent` the `extras` get lost in the process. I am using a `singleTop Activity`, so I set a break point at the `onNewIntent` and also my `handleIntent` to see which one was firing up when I clicked on the notification.

When I clicked the notification, it fired up my `handleIntent` method. I thought a `singleTop` activity will fire the `onNewIntent` method?

Why are my `Intent extras` being lost in the process when creating the `notification`? I debugged the `intent` and it shows `Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=168]`. How do I `unparcel` the Bundle?

**Activity that handles the intent**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    mPrefs = new SharedPrefs(this);
    mDb = DatabaseManager.getInstance(this);
    mVolleyManager = new VolleyManager(this);
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    setupToolbar();
    setupNavDrawer();
    setupBroadcastReceivers();
    setupUniversalImageLoader();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft = ViewManager.setFragmentAnimations(ft);

        if (!mPrefs.getDemoMode()) {
            if (!mPrefs.getLoggedIn()) {
                ft.add(R.id.container, LoginFragment.newInstance(), GlobalVars
                        .TAG_LOGIN_FRAGMENT).commit();
            }
            else {
                ft.add(R.id.container, BrowseFragment.newInstance(), GlobalVars.
                        TAG_BROWSE_FRAGMENT).commit();
            }
        }
    }

    // Handles intents mainly sent from GCM notification click events
    handleIntent();
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent();
}

private void handleIntent() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent.hasExtra(GlobalVars.KEY_EVENT)) {
        handleGcmIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

**Adding the extras to the intent and creating the notification**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(GlobalVars.KEY_EVENT, events);
        intent.putExtra(GlobalVars.KEY_GAME_DATE_ID, gameDate.getId());

        String text = getResources().getString(R.string.msg_found_match);
        createNotification(text, intent);

private void createNotification(String text, Intent intent) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context
            .NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("LovelUp")
            .setContentText(text)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(R.color.primary_blue, 2000, 2000);

    if (mPrefs.getNotificationVibrate()) {
        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000});
    }
    if (mPrefs.getNotificationSound()) {
        mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    }

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent
            .FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `putStringArrayListExtra` to add ArrayList to the bundle.

In your case:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra(GlobalVars.KEY_EVENT, events);
```

and then use `getStringArrayListExtra` to retrieve data.

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)) (search for `putStringArrayListExtra`)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Intent.putExtra(String key, <Whatever> value)` doesn't accept ArrayList as a value. Your code goes past compiler because ArrayList is Serializable, it is accepted but with ArrayList something else is wrong.

You should use `[putStringArrayListExtra()][1]`