# Get extra from notificationIntent in activity while launchMode="singleTop" with multiple notifications

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm having issues with mutiple notification while `putExtra` using `PendingIntent`. In `Activity` `getStringExtra` fom `Intent` is returning last `putExtra` while generating `Notification`.

Let me explain complete scenario first and make me correct if i'm wrong.

First of all my `Activity`'s (let's say its `MainActivity`) `launchMode` is `singleTop`. i'm setting it into manifest.i.e.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    ...    />
```

Now i'm generating notifaction using this code,

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context,
            MainActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.putExtra("message", msg);
    Log.i(TAG, msg);
    notifyIntent.putExtra("title", notification_title);
    Log.i(TAG, notification_title);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            BeaconService.this, 0, notifyIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(notification_title).setContentText(msg)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    NOTIFICATION_ID++;
```

I'm also using flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`. but, `while clicking on any Notification (let's say we've 5 notifactions) it just returns the fifth extra put while generating Notification all top four notification extra are just like lost somewhere`.

In my `MainActivity` i've also override `onNewIntent` like,

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        // getIntent() should always return the most recent
        setIntent(intent);
        if (intent.hasExtra("message")) {
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        }
        if (intent.hasExtra("title")) {
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        }
    }
```

this extras returned are always from last notification's extra. I don't know where am i going wrong?

I've also tried some links but didn't find helpful solution.

[Intent extras being lost when sending with PendingIntent for GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571351/intent-extras-being-lost-when-sending-with-pendingintent-for-gcm)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't creating unique `PendingIntent`s. There must be a thousand answers to exactly this question on Stackoverflow.

When you call this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        BeaconService.this, 0, notifyIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The second time, it will find the first `PendingIntent` and return you a reference to it (Android will not create another one). Also, since you set `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, Android will modify the underlying `Intent` by overwriting the extras in the old `Intent` with the extras you provided in the new `Intent`. That's why it always only delivers one `Intent` and that `Intent` always has the last set of extras.

You need to make each `PendingIntent` unique. There are many ways to do this (setting different extras is NOT one of the ways). Try providing a unique number as the `requestCode` parameter to `PendingIntent.getActivity()`.

Comment: providing a unique number as the requestCode parameter to PendingIntent.getActivity() has worked thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@David Wasser thanks for your answer!

I just wanted to share a piece of code which i've used and solved my issue.

providing a unique number as the `requestCode` parameter to `PendingIntent.getActivity()` is the right solution with Multiple Notifications while `launchmode="singleTop"`.

`To provide unique` code as the `requestCode` what i've done is, placed `NOTIFICATION_ID` as `requestCode` i.e,

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        BeaconService.this, NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I've also found same [solution at here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538554/2064336).

That's the `perfect unique requestCode in my case`. I hope it will be helpful to others is well who are facing issue.